# Cyclic or Acyclic TBox

Tags: semantic-web, owl, description-logic

Is the following TBox *cyclic* or *acyclic*? If it is a cyclic TBox, how could it be converted to an acyclic one?

> A ⊑ ¬E
>   E ⊑ ¬A

Comment: Do you know what it means for a TBox to be cyclic or acyclic?

Comment: An acyclic TBox is a finite set of concept definitions that it: (i) does not contain multiple definitions; (ii) does not contain cyclic definitions (directly or indirectly). The above ones are equal, so I can use only one of them. Thanks.

Comment: Neither of these is a concept *definition*, though.  They are provide necessary conditions of the classes A and E, but not sufficient conditions.  That said, I've provided an answer that explains how you might rewrite their meaning in a more direct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A ⊑ ¬E
>   E ⊑ ¬A

This TBox doesn't really say anything except that the classes A and E are disjoint.  The subclass relations could be read as implications:

- If something is an A, then it is *not* an E.
- If something is an E, then it is *not* an A.

To express disjointness in description logics, you'd typically say that the intersection of disjoint classes is equivalent, or a subclass, of the bottom concept, ⊥, which by definition has no instances.  &bot is also the complement of the top concept, ⊤, which contains everything.  Thus you could say any of the following:

> A ⊓ E ⊑ ⊥

> A ⊓ E ≡ ⊥

> A ⊓ E ⊑ ¬⊤

> A ⊓ E ≡ ¬⊤

Answer (score 0):

To add what Joshua said, disjointedness representation depends upon the language you use. Example: EL doesnt support bottom and negation.

The axioms you have written is not cyclic.

Cycle:  antecedent and consequent of an axiom should have at least one common predicate (Concept or role).

If an axiom contains  a cycle, you have to adopt fixpoint semantics to make it unequivocal.

To the best of my knowledge, axioms are meant to get induced knowledge. Converting a cyclic axiom to an acylic axiom: It is difficult to produce similar semantics.

Answer (score 0):

How to convert the following TBox axioms into an acyclic Tbox:

```
 A \sqsubseteq \lnot E
 \exists R.A \sqcap \lnot B \sqsubseteq C
 C \sqsubseteq B \sqcup A
 C = A \sqcup D
 A \sqcap \exists R.E \sqsubseteq D
```